# Meteor show and hide Template on click

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I want to show one template instead of another template on a button click. Similar to the "add comment" link in a StackOverFlow question. In the below example I want to replace {{> newCommentLink}} with {{> postEditor}}

```
<template name="main">
  {{#each posts}}
        {{> posts}}
   {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="posts">
  {{#each comments}}
        {{> comment}}
  {{/each}}
  {{> newCommentLink}}
</template>
```

If this is not possible, is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [reactive variable](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-var) to determine which template to show:

```
Template.posts.onCreated(function() {
    this.newCommentLink = new ReactiveVar(true);
});

Template.posts.helpers({
    shouldShowNewCommentLink() {
      return Template.instance().newCommentLink.get();
    }
});

Template.posts.events({
    'click button': function(event, template) {
      template.newCommentLink.set(!template.newCommentLink.get());
    }
});
```

In template:

```
<template name="posts">
  {{#each comments}}
        {{> comment}}
  {{/each}}
  <button class="btn btn-default">Click me to switch...</button>
  {{#if shouldShowNewCommentLink}}
    {{> newCommentLink}}
  {{else}}
    {{>postEditor}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Comment: doesn't this create only one variable? and only one event listener? there are more than one post. right?

Comment: The variable and event should be scoped to just the current template instance, so you would have a variable/event for each instance of post.